# Can't change Bootstrap 5 carousel indicator border radius

Tags: css, button, carousel, bootstrap-5, border-radius

I'm using carousel component of Bootstrap 5.1. I realized that no matter what i do i cannot add border-radius to the carousel indicators. They are always rectangle and not accepting border radius. But in inspector it curiously shows indicators (html buttons) do have a border radius but not displayed. I'm so confused. I tried to style .carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] in css, added inline border-radius styling in html. None of them worked.

Comment: Can you please add your code? Or provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Have you tried to use Bootstrap utility classes such as `rounded`, `rounded-1`, `rounded-2`, etc.?

Comment: @tromgy i have. And it doesn't work.

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: Here is the pen: https://codepen.io/megavolkan/pen/ExXwEVM

Comment: You cant see the border stylings you are applying because there are invisible borders on the top and bottom.

Comment: They do have border radius, it's just the border is transparent. I think the reason they made it transparent was to increase the clickable area. The white indicators are quite tiny by themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```css
.carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height:6px;
}
```

The elements have a transparent border which are being styled with a border radius, but can not be seen because they are transparent.

Comment: That's right, i completely missed transparent borders. This way it works now. Thank you.